# How do I get secondary monitor to display separate video feed in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I need to have a rather unusual setup where the primary monitor must be isolated from the secondary monitor. The mouse pointer must stay in the primary monitor at all times while the secondary monitor must still be able to show a video feed.

I have tried to make use of position.cx in the registry but it did not isolate the secondary monitor.

I need second monitor to be dedicated to VirtualBox. Where a secondary mouse and keyboard will be "snatched" by the VBOX OS.

Comment: I edited your question a little to improve it (made the title relevant to what you are doing and removed the signature as they are not allowed). Please [edit] your question to add more detail about your setup. What type of graphics card(s) are you using, type of connection, etc. More info is better for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only concern is the mouse, then you can use software to "clip" the cursor and restrict it to the primary monitor. An example of this would be [MouseJail](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/MouseJail/). Another example would be [Dual Monitor Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortool/). The task can also be done with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/42697-mousetrap2mon-trap-mouse-to-chosen-monitor/).

Another option you might consider is running two Virtual machines. Having each capture a different keyboard and mouse and displayed on separate screens.

Comment: Dual Monitor Tools seems like the best solution in my case. It does not run smoothly, but it does keep the mouse in place.

Answer (score 1):

Won't extended desktops do the trick? http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/monitors-extended-desktop-3-check/ (Or Windows+P)

To restrict the mouse to the primary screen you could use [Mousetrap](http://tom.zickel.org/mousetrap/)

Also see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15751/when-extending-my-desktop-across-multiple-monitors-how-can-i-limit-my-mouse-t

Comment: Yes Extended desktops does give the view, but it do not keep the mouse from going to the second desktop.